# grep and regex : Print lines that contain character N times in unknown combinations

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file containing strings like

```
xxxbbxxxbxbx
xxxbxxxxbxxx
xxbxxxbxxbxx
bbbbxxxxxxxx
bxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxbxxxxxxx
xxxxbbxxbbxx
xxxxbbbbxxxx
xxxxbbbbbxxx
```

In reality the file `x` is really a variety of uninteresting alphabetical characters. I want to use grep to print out all the lines where `b` occurs *exactly* four times.

If I use `grep -e "[^b]b[^b]\{0,4\}b[^b]\{0,4\}b[^b]\{0,4\}b[^b]\{1,4\}" test.txt` it excludes the last line (I want), but also excludes line 4 (I don't want) where the line starts with `b`.

If I use `grep -e "b[^b]\{0,4\}b[^b]\{0,4\}b[^b]\{0,4\}b[^b]\{1,4\}" test.txt`, it catches line 4 (I want) but also the last line (I don't want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[^b]*b){4}[^b]*$
```

Use this with `grep -P` and `anchors`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/32

Answer (score 0):

You can try `([^b]*b){4}[^b]*`.

Comment: Add an explanation so that people can learn from your answer.